# cleanse-path vs resolve-path vs normalize-path vs simplify-path in Racket

Tags: path, racket

Racket appears to have 4 functions for making a canonical path, but each slightly different. They are [`cleanse-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Manipulating_Paths.html?q=cleanse-path#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._cleanse-path%29%29), [`resolve-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Manipulating_Paths.html?q=cleanse-path#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._resolve-path%29%29), [`simplify-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Manipulating_Paths.html?q=cleanse-path#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._simplify-path%29%29), and [`normalize-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/More_Path_Utilities.html?q=normalize-path#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpath..rkt%29._normalize-path%29%29).

Clearly these functions don't do the same thing as some of them take in different arguments. But the docs lack any examples here. So, what are the differences between these four very similar functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(memq (system-type 'os) '(unix macosx))`

- `cleanse-path` replaces `//` with `/`
- `resolve-path` resolves symbolic links
- `simplify-path` removes extra `..` and `.`
- `normalize-path` makes an absolute path and resolves symbolic links

(There's also [`simple-form-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/More_Path_Utilities.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpath..rkt%29._simple-form-path%29%29). This is probably what you want.)

Here's a sample interaction, using the 4 functions on a nonsense path:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.10.0.1.
> (current-directory (find-system-path 'sys-dir))
; now in /
> (cleanse-path "foo//bar/baz/..")
#<path:foo/bar/baz/..>
> (resolve-path "foo//bar/baz/..")
#<path:foo/bar/baz/..>
> (simplify-path "foo//bar/baz/..")
#<path:/foo/bar/>
> (normalize-path "foo//bar/baz/..")
; normalize-path: element within the input path is not a directory or does not
;   exist
;   element: /foo
```

And here's an example using `normalize-path` and `simple-form-path` on a symbolic link (on my computer):

```
Welcome to Racket v6.10.0.1.
> (current-directory "/usr/local/bin")
; now in /usr/local/bin
> (normalize-path "racket")
#<path:/Users/ben/code/racket/fork/racket/bin/racket>
> (simple-form-path "racket")
#<path:/usr/local/bin/racket>
```

If `(eq? (system-type 'os) 'windows)`, see the Racket docs about [Windows Paths](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/windowspaths.html)